# Improve experience for touch screen users: mouseenter function

Tags: javascript, jquery, touchscreen, mouseenter

Im loading images into a slideshow with ajax on mouseenter. I did this to limit the amount loaded on the page initially as there is multiple slideshows. I wondered how touchscreen users would deal with it, after testing, it doesnt work which is obviously not good.

Ive been looking into other alternatives and havent found anything that works brilliantly.

One thing that was on another Stack Overflow question was this bit of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hover').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('hover_effect');
    });
});
```

I tested this on my tablet and the result was mixed. My tablet popped up with a menu asking what I wanted to do with the link/image. When I cancel out of that and then click the "Next" link on the slideshow it works.

SO its not ideal because of the tablet menu popping up and how does the user know to tap and hold to get the desired effect.

Can anyone point me in another direction. Should I be looking at a JQuery solution, perhaps tying the mouseenter event with a click event on the slideshow controls?

Has anyone come up with a better solution than above?